# offsetof on standard-layout class?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
class Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << offsetof(Foo, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code could not compile using gcc-4.8.2 or vc++11. The error message is could not access private member b in class Foo.

But according to the standard, offsetof should support standard-layout class and Foo is a standard-layout class.

Is this a defect of gcc-4.8.2 or vc++11, or my understanding of the c++ standard is wrong?

Comment: It's just a macro. It can't magically access private members. I don't think there's even any standard hack that would let it access them by name, either.

Comment: @chris: There are well-known hacks to get to private members from outside the class, yes.

Comment: @BenVoigt, But by name in a macro?

Comment: @chris: The macro could use a helper function/class.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I suppose it could, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*offsetof* is defined as a *macro* and therefore it can not bypass the access controls and gain access to *private members*, we can see that this is the case by going to draft C++ standard section `17.6.1.2` *Headers* paragraph *5* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Names which are defined as macros in C **shall be defined as macros in the C++ standard** library, even if C grants license for implementation as functions. [ Note: The names defined as macros in C include the following: assert, **offsetof**, setjmp, va_arg, va_end, and va_start. —end note ]

**Update**

So there are hacks that can allow you to access the private member of a class in a standard way but if we go back to the C99 draft standard which the draft C++ standard falls back on for *offsetof* then we see in section `7.17` *Common definitions*  paragraph *3* says (*emphasis mine*):

```
   offsetof(type, member-designator)
```

> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of
>   which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by member-designator),
>   from the beginning of its structure (designated by type). The type and member designator
>   **shall be such that given**

```
   static type t;
```

> then the **expression &(t.member-designator) evaluates to an address constant**.

which won't be the case if you are trying to access a *private member* from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

class members default to private.
List them as public, or make Foo a struct (because struct members default to public) and the above works, else main isnt permitted to access b, and offsetof is considered an access.

Answer (score 0):

**Data members in a class are private by default**. they can be accessed from main only if it is declared under **public**.Or you can access them from main by **declaring a function in the class under public** and calling it from main. since the functions in the class can access the data members from the class,you can get access to the private data members.