# What is the purpose of standard-layout guarantees for "black box" types?

Tags: c++, mutex, atomic, standard-library, standard-layout

The C++ standard specifies that mutex, atomics or conditinal_variable are of standard-layout type.

What is the benefit of this specification? How a user can take advantage of this property?

And in general, what could I gain if a know a type is standard-layout without knowing the detail of its implementation?

Comment: A standard-layout type can be more readily consumed by other languages.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even when the other language is also C++? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your code talk with other programs, written in *different Programming Languages* than yours.

The ref mentions [C++ concepts: StandardLayoutType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType):

> Standard layout types are useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages.

Comment: You could use `std::offsetof` \o/

Comment: You mean this @YSC [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170578/offsetof-on-standard-layout-class)?

Comment: It seems that I can not know if there is a padding between members of standard-layout class. Are compiler allowed to add padding between members even if alignment would not require it?

Comment: @Oliv this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364483/determining-the-alignment-of-c-c-structures-in-relation-to-its-members) can help!

Comment: @gsamaras not specifically, but it applies.

Comment: Same comment as for ProgrammerDude it would help me if you gave me an exemple, where one use a standard-layout struct to communicate with an other program

Answer (score 2):

From [this standard layout reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType):

> Standard layout types are useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages.

For example, if you build a mixed C and C++ application, the C structures will be *standard layout* and can be used interchangeably between the parts written in C and the parts written in C++. This is often very crucial for being able to use operating system native functions and structures.

Comment: Nice answer, glad we agree! =)

Comment: I honestly do not see how, it would help me if you gavee me an exemple?

Comment: @Oliv There are many libraries written for C. What if you want to use one of those libraries in your C++ application? What is that C library have a structure? Because that structure will be *standard layout* you can create instance of it in your C++ program, and pass pointers to it (or even copies of instances) to the C library functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But mutex is a C++ structure, so can I pass a mutex to a C library, otherwise what is the point of having mutex standard-layout?

Comment: @Oliv So your question isn't about standard layout in general, but about why just *those* structures are specified as standard layout? Perhaps you should narrow down your question then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actualy StoryTeller did it a few hour ago. He has narrowed the question to "black-boxes" types. Then I am not sure if I have to precise that the struct is declared in a C++ header file, since my question is about C++?